# How to add image in wordpress custom plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, custom-field, images

I am looking for how to add images in a custom database table using WordPress code

I am new in WordPress plugin development. I've created code for a plugin named **store plugin**. I've taken fields like `store_id`, `store_name`, `description`, `image`, `address`, `latitude and longitude`.

I have successfully inserted other data into my `store_db` database.

Please help me with how to add an image and also I have a query on that my data is also inserted into the `wp_posts` table default

I've my own table that is inserting data successfully but I don't want to store my records at the posts table.

**Here is my code:**

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Store Plugin 
 * Plugin URI: https://example.com/my-plugin
 * Description: This is a description of my hello world sample plugin.
 * Version: 2.3.1
 * Author: Khushbu 
 * Author URI: https://example.com
 * License: GPL v2 or later
 * License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 */
function db_active() {
  global $wpdb;
  $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'store_db'; 
  $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
  $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table (
    store_id int(20) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    store_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    image VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    latitude VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    longitude VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
  ) $charset_collate;";  
  require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
  $result = dbDelta($sql);
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'db_active');

function db_deactive() {
  global $wpdb;
  $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'store_db'; 
  $sql = "DROP TABLE $table;";
  $wpdb->query($sql);
}
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'db_deactive');

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_your_fields_meta_box');

function create_post_your_post() {
    register_post_type('store_post',
        array(
            'labels'       => array(
      'name'         => __('Store Post'),
            ),
            'public'       => true,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'has_archive'  => true,
            'supports'     => array(
      'title',
      'editor',
      'excerpt',
      'thumbnail',
            ),
            'taxonomies'   => array(
      'post_tag',
      'category',
            )
        )
    );
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'store_post');
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'store_post');
}

add_action('init', 'create_post_your_post');

function your_custom_meta_box_content($post) {
  $store_id = $post->ID;
  $image = get_post_meta($store_id,'image',true);
  $address = get_post_meta($store_id, 'address', true);
  $latitude = get_post_meta($store_id, 'latitude', true);
  $longitude = get_post_meta($store_id, 'longitude', true);
  ?>  
  <b><label for="your-meta-field">Image:</label></b>
  <input type="file" name="your_meta_field[image]" id="your_meta_field[image]" value="<?php echo esc_attr($image); ?>"><br><br> 

  <b><label for="your_meta_field">Address:</label></b>
  <textarea name="your_meta_field[address]" id="your_meta_field[address]" rows="3" cols="30" style="width:500px;"><?php echo esc_attr($address);?></textarea><br><br>

  <b><label for="your_meta_field">Latitude:</label></b>
  <input type="text" name="your_meta_field[latitude]" id="your_meta_field[latitude]" value="<?php echo esc_attr($latitude); ?>"><br><br>

  <b><label for="your_meta_field">Longitude:</label></b>
  <input type="text" name="your_meta_field[longitude]" id="your_meta_field[longitude]" value="<?php echo esc_attr($longitude); ?>"><br><br>

  <?php wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__), 'your_meta_box_nonce'); ?>
  <?php
}

function add_your_fields_meta_box() {
  add_meta_box(
    'your_custom_meta_box',          // ID of the meta box
    'Location Information',          // Title of the meta box
    'your_custom_meta_box_content',  // Callback function to generate the content
    'store_post',                     // Custom post type (your_post)
    'normal',                        // Placement - 'normal', 'advanced', 'side'
    'high'                           // Priority - 'high', 'core', 'default', 'low'
  );
}

function save_your_custom_meta_box_data($post_id) {
  if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
    return;
  }
  if (!isset($_POST['your_meta_box_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['your_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
    return;
  }
  if ('store_post' !== get_post_type($post_id)) {
    return;
  }
  $meta_fields = isset($_POST['your_meta_field']) ? $_POST['your_meta_field'] : array();
  if(isset($meta_fields['image'])){
    update_post_meta($post_id,'image',sanitize_text_field($meta_fields['image']));
  }
  if ( isset( $meta_fields['address'] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'address', sanitize_text_field( $meta_fields['address'] ) );  
  }
  if ( isset( $meta_fields['latitude'] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'latitude', sanitize_text_field( $meta_fields['latitude'] ) );  
  }
  if ( isset( $meta_fields['longitude'] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'longitude', sanitize_text_field( $meta_fields['longitude'] ) );
  }

  if (isset($meta_fields['image']) && isset($meta_fields['address']) && isset($meta_fields['latitude']) && isset($meta_fields['longitude'])) {
    $store_name = get_the_title($post_id);
    $description = get_post_field('post_content', $post_id);
    $image = _sanitize_text_fields($meta_fields['image']);
    $address = sanitize_text_field($meta_fields['address']);
    $latitude = sanitize_text_field($meta_fields['latitude']);
    $longitude = sanitize_text_field($meta_fields['longitude']);

    global $wpdb;
    $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'store_db';
    $existing_record = $wpdb->get_row(
      $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE store_id = %d", $post_id)
    );

    if ($existing_record) {
      // If a record exists, update the existing record
      $wpdb->update(
        $table,
        array(
          'store_name' => $store_name,
          'description' => $description,
          'image' => $image,
          'address' => $address,
          'latitude' => $latitude,
          'longitude' => $longitude,
        ),
        array('store_id' => $post_id),
        array('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'),
        array('%d')
      );
    } else {
      // If no record exists, insert a new record
      $wpdb->insert(
        $table,
        array(
          'store_id' => $post_id,
          'store_name' => $store_name,
          'description' => $description,
          'image' => $image,
          'address' => $address,
          'latitude' => $latitude,
          'longitude' => $longitude,
        ),
        array('%d', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')
      );
    }
  }
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_your_custom_meta_box_data');
// my changes completed
?>
```